# Coldfusion MySQL Query of Queries date selections

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, date-format, qoq

I'm trying to query a query in Coldfusion with a timestamp field (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss) reformatted to a specific date. I can get the original query to "date format" fine but I can't get the query of query to select the date. I have tried changing the cf_sql queryparam to different values but I keep getting a 0 RecordCount. The db field is a varchar and I tried changing that to a timestamp and it still didn't work. Any ideas what I'm not seeing?

```
<cfquery datasource="#DataSource#" name="rsAll">
  SELECT ID, date_format(DateSent, '%Y-%m-%d') As DateSent 
  FROM 'workorders'
  WHERE RelCompID_FK = '#SESSION.Auth.CompID#' 
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="rsAllDay" dbtype="query">
  SELECT *
  FROM rsAll
  WHERE  DateSent  = <cfqueryparam value="2010-03-03" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: *The db field is a varchar* Do not store dates as strings. Store dates *as dates*. Then you do not have to worry about these kinds of implicit conversion problems. Plus you can take advantage of the built in date functions without all the conversions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL `date_format()` function returns a string, not a datetime object, so when running your query of query in ColdFusion you would use the `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` datatype instead of the `CF_SQL_DATE` datatype.  The value passed in would need to exactly match the value returned from the first query as well to match.

Other considerations:

1) Use `CFDUMP` to display the results of the first query to ensure that the data types returned are what you're expecting.

2) Use `CFQUERYPARAM` in the WHERE clause of your first query as well.

Comment: Thanks that helped! I ended up using `STR_TO_DATE( DateSent, '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AS DateSent` instead of `date_format(DateSent, '%Y-%m-%d') As DateSent` to convert it to a datetime object and then  was able to parse the original query with a CF query of queries.

Comment: Awesome, this post helped me a lot. I was also using cf_sql_date instead of cf_sql_varchar